# Changing columns with rows

Tags: r

I'm not sure how to ask this question properly and that's probably why I can't figure it out.

So basically when using mtcars dataset I pick only 3 columns let's say the name of the car, mpg, and cyl. So now I want to have a data frame where I will have the number of cyl. on the Y axis.

Basically, I will have the name of the car on the x-axis, then in the y-axis I will have cyl nr like 4/6/8, and finally inside the cells the mpg.

Rearranging the data frame or something, but I can't find anything helpful, please point me in the right direction mighty stackoverflow!

Comment: Do you want the output to have one row, 14 (matching the number of cars for cyl = 8, the most common), or 32 (one per car), or something else?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "car on the x-axis"?

Comment: Are you talking about a data structure or a figure?

Comment: This is what i want `Name <- c("a1", "a1", "a1", "a2", "a2", "a2", "a3", "a3", "a3")
Absorbance <- c(25, 15, 20, 5, 10, 15, 50, 60, 40)
Wavelength <- c(11, 55, 66, 11, 55, 66, 11, 55, 66)
df <- data.frame(Name, Absorbance, Wavelength)

New.name <- c("a1", "a2", "a3")
One <- c(25, 5, 50)
Two <- c(15, 10, 60)
Three <- c(20, 15, 40)

new.df <-data.frame(New.name,One, Two, Three)`

I have no idea how to make this comment look better, thought the code would be in sqare

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this?

```
library(tidyverse)
mtcars |>
  rownames_to_column(var = "car") |>
  select(1:3) |>
  pivot_wider(names_from = car, values_from = mpg)
```

Result

```
# A tibble: 3 × 33
    cyl `Mazda RX4` `Mazda RX4 Wag` `Datsun 710` `Hornet 4 Drive` `Hornet Sportabout` Valiant `Duster 360` `Merc 240D` `Merc 230` `Merc 280`
  <dbl>       <dbl>           <dbl>        <dbl>            <dbl>               <dbl>   <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>
1     6          21              21         NA               21.4                NA      18.1         NA          NA         NA         19.2
2     4          NA              NA         22.8             NA                  NA      NA           NA          24.4       22.8       NA  
3     8          NA              NA         NA               NA                  18.7    NA           14.3        NA         NA         NA  
# ℹ 22 more variables: `Merc 280C` <dbl>, `Merc 450SE` <dbl>, `Merc 450SL` <dbl>, `Merc 450SLC` <dbl>, `Cadillac Fleetwood` <dbl>,
#   `Lincoln Continental` <dbl>, `Chrysler Imperial` <dbl>, `Fiat 128` <dbl>, `Honda Civic` <dbl>, `Toyota Corolla` <dbl>,
#   `Toyota Corona` <dbl>, `Dodge Challenger` <dbl>, `AMC Javelin` <dbl>, `Camaro Z28` <dbl>, `Pontiac Firebird` <dbl>, `Fiat X1-9` <dbl>,
#   `Porsche 914-2` <dbl>, `Lotus Europa` <dbl>, `Ford Pantera L` <dbl>, `Ferrari Dino` <dbl>, `Maserati Bora` <dbl>, `Volvo 142E` <dbl>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the keyword you are looking for is *contingency table* a form of (sparse)-matrix.
You can use xtabs and formula syntax. The frist argument of the formula `mpg` will be in the cells and will be explained by `cyl` and the `rownames(mtcars)` containing the names of each car. The second argument of xtabs is the dataframe itself.

```
xtabs(mpg~cyl+rownames(mtcars),mtcars)|>
 as.data.frame.matrix()
```

After xtabs use as.dataframe.matrix to keep it in the matrix form, otherwise it will be converted to a long table.

Comment: Be aware that this will add 0's instead of NA

Comment: I cant find this as.dataframe.matrix function. What package is it part of?

Comment: i missed a dot its as.data.frame.matrix . its a base function.

Comment: Nope im still getting the error "Error in as.data.frame.martix(xtabs(mpg ~ cyl + rownames(mtcars), mtcars)) : 
  could not find function "as.data.frame.martix""

Comment: This is what i want `Name <- c("a1", "a1", "a1", "a2", "a2", "a2", "a3", "a3", "a3")
Absorbance <- c(25, 15, 20, 5, 10, 15, 50, 60, 40)
Wavelength <- c(11, 55, 66, 11, 55, 66, 11, 55, 66)
df <- data.frame(Name, Absorbance, Wavelength)

New.name <- c("a1", "a2", "a3")
One <- c(25, 5, 50)
Two <- c(15, 10, 60)
Three <- c(20, 15, 40)

new.df <-data.frame(New.name,One, Two, Three)`

Comment: its matrix not martix